# Cannot "make" the RethinkDb from the source

Tags: debian, rethinkdb, debian-based, rethinkdb-python

I was trying to install RethinkDb on a fresh debian instance(from google cloud) which has around 1.7gb memory and 10gb storage. Everything till configure went great but i got this error while running the make command!

````
[1/306] CC build/release/obj/client_protocol/server.o
src/client_protocol/server.cc: In member function ‘size_t http_conn_cache_t::sha_hasher_t::operator()(const conn_key_t&) const’:
src/client_protocol/server.cc:177:16: error: aggregate ‘EVP_MD_CTX c’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     EVP_MD_CTX c;                                                                        ^
src/build.mk:390: recipe for target 'build/release/obj/client_protocol/server.o' failed
make[1]: *** [build/release/obj/client_protocol/server.o] Error 1
Makefile:52: recipe for target 'make' failed
make: *** [make] Error 2```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error : aggregate 'first one' has incomplete type and cannot be defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799906/error-aggregate-first-one-has-incomplete-type-and-cannot-be-defined)

Comment: you might be missing openSSL headers, because that's where `EVP_MD_CTX` should be defined.

Comment: I am also facing same issue