# Template class full specialization in CPP: "error: aggregate has incomplete type and cannot be defined" g++

Tags: c++, templates

Trying to delcare full spec of template class in header after generic template definition and to define full spec in cpp file.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "generic_template.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << advance( 100, 1 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << advance( 200.4, 4.8 ) << std::endl;

    TestSpec< int > tsInt;
    TestSpec< void > tsVoid; //error

    return 0;
}
```

generic_template.hpp

```
#ifndef TEMP_SPEC_STUDY_HPP
#define TEMP_SPEC_STUDY_HPP

template< typename T >
T advance( T begin, T coef )
{
    return begin + coef;
}

template<>
double advance< double >( double begin, double coef );

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template< typename T >
class TestSpec
{};

template<>
class TestSpec< void >;

#endif // TEMP_SPEC_STUDY_HPP
```

spec.cpp

```
#include <cmath>

#include "generic_template.hpp"

template<>
double advance< double >( double begin, double coef )
{
    return ceil( begin + coef );
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<>
class TestSpec< void >
{};
```

trying to compile this with

```
g++ -std=c++17 -g main.cpp spec.cpp -o main
```

```
In function 'int main()': main.cpp:13:22: error: aggregate
'TestSpec<void> tsVoid' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     TestSpec< void > tsVoid;
                      ^~~~~~
```

Comment: If you want to create an object of some type, the compiler needs to see the class definition - plain class/struct or template doesn't change anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799906/error-aggregate-first-one-has-incomplete-type-and-cannot-be-defined

Comment: @Mat so CPP is used to define functions and  members only?

Comment: The important part is that the compiler must have seen a definition (not just a declaration) for a struct/class before you can use it to create an object. (In particular, it must know the size and whether there are appropriate constructors.) `.cpp`, `.h`, whatever - the compiler doesn't care about how your source is organized, only that it has what it needs to work with when it needs it.

Comment: void is not a type that can be used like int, double etc. It is only used to either tell the compiler that a function has no return value       void function();   or when you are declaring a void pointer such as      void *pPtr;

Comment: @stackoverblown void can be used as template argument/parameter.